# Can I use any custom UI framework with Amazon Web Serviecs

Tags: javascript, user-interface, amazon-web-services

I am planning to use AWS as a middleware platform and have a custom built UI, preferably some JS based UI framework as the frontend. My question naturally is that can I have that kind of a system or will I be forced to use the UI that comes along with the AWS system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*quizzical*

Amazon Web Services is the name for the infrastructure-based "Cloud Computing" services (e.g., servers, storage, databases). There is no UI. They're literally raw web services.

Unless of course you're talking about a different Amazon service that is *not AWS*, such as Amazon Flexible Payments Service (FPS), Amazon Associates (Product Advertising) or Amazon Marketplace Web Service (MWS).

Comment: so you mean I can build a separate web application and use it to connect to the hosted services platform (AWS).